# On a method of clock gating with a latch

Tags: digital-logic, clock, latch, clock-gating

My textbook (CMOS VLSI Design: A Circuits and Systems Perspective, 4th edition, by Weste and Harris) gives the following discussion of a particular method of clock gating into some digital block.

[image]

I am trying to understand Figure 5.7 in particular. The somewhat parsimonious explanation given for the method is, again, below:

> The clock enable must be stable while the clock is active (i.e., 1 for systems
> using positive edge-triggered flip-flops). Figure 5.7 shows how an enable latch can be used to ensure the enable does not change before the clock falls.

Why does this "work how we want it to"? The `clk` signal is doing its usual 50% duty cycle square wave action, and the active-low `Enable Latch` therefore maintains the output of the `Enable Logic` block while `clk` is high. But what would be the problem without the `Enable Latch`? Is the idea that *if* the `Enable Logic` went back high and we didn't have `Enable Latch`, then we might get violations on the registers (I guess these wouldn't be called hold or setup time violations since the `Clock Gater` output is not a data input, but a clock input to the registers) around the positive edge of the clock? How does the `Enable Latch` preclude this? Is this the issue being solved by it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latch-based clock gate logic helps to prevent glitches on the clock output signal from the clock gate, assuming appropriate timing constraints are applied when synthesizing/implementing the design.

Narrow clock pulses can produce timing violations in the register (flip-flop), which typically has a minimum clock pulse width requirement.

Here are some example waveforms where the input signals to the clock gate are `en` and `clk`.

Let's assume there are 2 types of clock gate for comparison:

- AND-based: a simple AND gate, with output `cg_and`
- Latch-based: similar to your Figure 5.7, with output `cg_lat`

[image: waves]

As shown in the waves at time 75ns, `cg_and` has a very narrow pulse (glitch), whereas `cg_lat` does not.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure I follow. *Given* that the latch is there, how does it help us avoid the timing violations? Would it be possible to talk about a specific example of inputs which shows that *without* the latch we get some violation, but *with* the latch we get none?

Comment: @EE18: I updated my answer with waveforms from a simple Verilog simulation I ran, plus an explanation.